# Service Worker not getting updated automatically in Progressive Web Application

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

When I change some code in service worker,I expect to update previous service worker in the browsers.I have read that any changes in service-worker.js automatically refreshes it in the browser
 This is my service worker code:

```
var dataCacheName = 'demo-v5';

var filesToCache = [
  '/',
  '/Home/Index',
  '/Home/AboutUs'  
];
self.addEventListener('install', function (e) {
    console.log('[Service Worker] Install');
    e.waitUntil(
      caches.open(dataCacheName).then(function (cache) {
          console.log('[Service Worker] Caching app shell');
          return cache.addAll(filesToCache);
      })
    );
});
self.addEventListener('activate', function(e) {
    console.log('[ServiceWorker] Activated');
    caches.keys()
    e.waitUntil(

        // Get all the cache keys (cacheName)
        caches.keys().then(function(cacheNames) {
            return Promise.all(cacheNames.map(function(thisCacheName) {

                // If a cached item is saved under a previous cacheName
                if (thisCacheName !== dataCacheName) {

                    // Delete that cached file
                    console.log('[ServiceWorker] Removing Cached Files from Cache - ', thisCacheName);
                    return caches.delete(thisCacheName);
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log('Else- ', thisCacheName);
                }
            }));
        })
    ); // end e.waitUntil

  //  return self.clients.claim();
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function (e) {
    console.log('[Service Worker] Fetch', e.request.url);
    var dataUrl = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql';
    if (e.request.url.indexOf(dataUrl) > -1) {
      e.respondWith(
          caches.open(dataCacheName).then(function (cache) {
              return fetch(e.request).then(function (response) {
                  cache.put(e.request.url, response.clone());
                  return response;
              });
          })
        );
    } else {

        e.respondWith(
          caches.match(e.request).then(function (response) {
              return response || fetch(e.request);
          })
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for your reply.
The Actual problem was with `filesToCache`.The root directory i.e "/"

```
var filesToCache = [
//  '/',
'/Home/Index',
'/Home/AboutUs'  
 ];
```

should be commented here.
My service-worker class was also getting cached and every time it was picking it from the cache after refresh also.

Comment: The comment regarding cached service worker is simply not true, but it's super confusing.

IF you load the service worker URL in your browser, the service worker will have a fetch event for the service worker itself, and you can cache it in that BUT the browser will NEVER use the cache before checking for updates.

Comment: It was using it from cache. I was able to see it in the network tab from the chrome developer's tools

Comment: Browsers will NEVER use a service worker from the cache. I have discussed this with Chrome engineers and spec authors..

Comment: okay I can show an example. I'm using it with .NET application.

Comment: @GauntFace Hope that was true, but looks like Chrome (60, macOS) still caches the service worker. That happens even if you call `register` and then you close and reload all tabs... Probably a bug. I've noticed that many times while dealing with web push notifications: I am pretty sure about that because I have also [inspected the SW](http://blog.pushpad.xyz/2017/05/inspect-service-workers-with-chrome/).

Comment: @GauntFace Maybe my issue lies in the fact that there's no `Cache-Control` header in the response: what is the default in that case? Probably Chrome caches the SW. I should try with an explicit `Cache-Control: no-cache`.

Comment: Chrome will listen to cache headers for a max of 24 hours.

Answer (score 2):

The changes in service worker will reflect in second refresh of your page. If It is not updating even on second refresh than look for service worker errors in Chrome Developer Console (I hope you already use it). It will be under

> Applications -> Service Worker

in chrome Developer tools (Latest stable Chrome version).

Open Chrome Developer tools by Clicking `Ctrl + Shift + I` or `Right click -> Inspect Element`.

**NOTE:** If you want service worker to update on first refresh then change your install event to -

```
self.addEventListener('install', function (e) {
    console.log('[Service Worker] Install');
    e.waitUntil(
      caches.open(dataCacheName).then(function (cache) {
          console.log('[Service Worker] Caching app shell');
          return cache.addAll(filesToCache);
      }).then(function(e){
        return self.skipWaiting();
      })
    );
});
```